# Find objects that are supported through Bulk API

Tags: standard-objects, bulk-api

I am querying through a list of objects through salesforce and some of the objects are not supported through bulk api. For example, AcceptedEventRelation. Is there a way to check if the objects are supported through Bulk API or not. There seems to be less information about what objects are supported through Bulk API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the documentation does not explicitly give a list of the objects that throw the "`____ is not supported by the Bulk API`" exception, but it tends to be metadata objects as opposed to descriptive data objects, including:

- List item
- CaseStatus
- ContractStatus
- KnowledgeArticle
- KnowledgeArticleVersion
- KnowledgeArticleVersionHistory
- KnowledgeArticleViewStat
- KnowledgeArticleVoteStat
- LeadStatus
- OpportunityStage
- PartnerRole
- RecentlyViewed
- SolutionStatus
- TaskPriority
- UserRecordAccess

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000Am1GIAS

Answer (score 3):

Here're the list of objects I've found which are not support the Bulk API:

- AcceptedEventRelation
- CaseStatus
- ContractStatus
- KnowledgeArticle
- KnowledgeArticleVersion
- KnowledgeArticleVersionHistory
- KnowledgeArticleViewStat
- KnowledgeArticleVoteStat
- LeadStatus
- OpportunityStage
- PartnerRole
- RecentlyViewed
- SolutionStatus
- TaskPriority
- UserRecordAccess
- ContentFolderItem
- DeclinedEventRelation
- EventWhoRelation
- TaskStatus
- TaskWhoRelation
- UndecidedEventRelation

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the list above, looks like Bulk API doesn't support  Knowledge__DataCategorySelection as well, however, instead of `is not supported by the Bulk API` error, it returns `InvalidJob : No create/update access for object:Knowledge__DataCategorySelection`

- AcceptedEventRelation
- CaseStatus
- ContractStatus
- KnowledgeArticle
- KnowledgeArticleVersion
- KnowledgeArticleVersionHistory
- KnowledgeArticleViewStat
- KnowledgeArticleVoteStat
- LeadStatus
- OpportunityStage
- PartnerRole
- RecentlyViewed
- SolutionStatus
- TaskPriority
- UserRecordAccess
- ContentFolderItem
- DeclinedEventRelation
- EventWhoRelation
- TaskStatus
- TaskWhoRelation
- UndecidedEventRelation
- Knowledge__DataCategorySelection